# How do i make a TabNavigator button push a modal screen with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using the React Navigation tab navigator https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab how do I make one of the tab buttons push the screen up as a full screen modal?  I see the stack navigator has a `mode=modal` option.  how do I get that mode to be used when clicking on the `TakePhoto` tab button?  Clicking on it currently still shows the tab bar on the bottom.

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  TakePhoto: {
    screen: PhotoPickerScreen, // how can I have this screen show up as a full screen modal?
  },
});
```

Comment: How did you solve this? I've been trying to figure it out for a while

Comment: I have given answer here and i am using react-navigation-5.*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65201694/12189049

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, there is no support in [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) to change the way of presentation on the fly from `default` to `modal` (see the discussion about this [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/232#issuecomment-286973451)). I ran into the same issue and solved it by using a very top `StackNavigator` with `headerMode` set to `none` and `mode` set to `modal`:

```
const MainTabNavigator = TabNavigator(
    {
        Tab1Home: { screen: Tab1Screen },
        Tab2Home: { screen: Tab2Screen }
    }
);

const LoginRegisterStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen }
});

const ModalStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    MainTabNavigator:          { screen: MainTabNavigator            },
    LoginScreenStackNavigator: { screen: LoginRegisterStackNavigator }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode:       'modal'
});
```

This allows me to do the following (using redux) in `Tab1Screen` and `Tab2Screen` to bring up the modal view from wherever I want:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreenStackNavigator');
```

Comment: Can you call this.props from inside a tab button? How?

Comment: @IamLasse You mean from a screen inside a tab or the tab button itself? "unfortunately" i was using redux so I think I have a different case :-)

Comment: I also use redux. But I can't dispatch an event to open the popup modal or call the props from within the main navigator stack where the nav configuration is.

Comment: Hi.  I will do as above code to change tab1 to tab2. its working fine, but in I want to update in tab2. How its possible tab change to update view. because its lifecycle doesn't call.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKekeisen This worked well for me!  One thing to note: if you want a nav header to appear in the LoginScreenStackNavigator, you need to set its headerMode to screen in its options otherwise it will inherit the none value from its outer nested nav.

Comment: Thanks, it works, only downside is when it's transparent, you can't see another screen underneath, because it's a navigator overall... :( I read in their github issues, they said it's currently impossible with only react navigation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I like this solution

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is still relevant for you, but i've managed to find away to achieve this.

So i've managed to get it working by using the tabBarComponent inside the tabNavigatorConifg, you can stop the tab navigation from navigating depending on the index.

```
   tabBarComponent: ({jumpToIndex, ...props, navigation}) => (
        <TabBarBottom
            {...props}
            jumpToIndex={index => {
                if (index === 2) {
                    navigation.navigate('camera')
                }
                else {
                    jumpToIndex(index)
                }
            }}
        />

    )
```

Once you've done this, my method of showing the view modally on top of the tab views was to put the tabnavigator inside of a stacknavigatior and then just navigate to a new screen inside of the stacknavigator.

Comment: I dont get this part "Once you've done this, my method of showing the view modally on top of the tab views was to put the tabnavigator inside of a stacknavigatior and then just navigate to a new screen inside of the stacknavigator." Wouldn't you put the stack navigator inside of the tab not outside it?

Comment: Thanks to _Thomas_ and _TomTom_, combination of both solutions work like a charm for me (even without Redux).

Answer (score 4):

`react-navigation`'s bottomTabNavigator has a `tabBarOnPress` navigation option you can use to override tab presses:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress

```
const AppContainer = createStackNavigator(
  {
    default: createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        TAB_0: Stack0,
        TAB_1: Stack1,
        TAB_2: Stack2,
        TAB_3: View // plain rn-view, or any old unused screen
      },
      {
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          // other tab navigation options...
          tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
            if (navigation.state.key === 'TAB_3') {
              navigation.navigate('tabToOpenAsModal');
            } else {
              defaultHandler();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ),
    tabToOpenAsModal: {
      screen: TabToOpenAsModalScreen
    }
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);
```

If you nest your tab navigator within a stack navigator with a modal, you can open this when the tab bar button is pressed. Since the modal was opened and not the tab, when the modal is closed the app returns to the screen that was visible before the modal tab was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the tab bar go away is to hide the tabBar with `visible: false`:

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  TakePhoto: {
    screen: PhotoPickerScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBar: {
        visible: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

However, that does not seem to trigger any transition to fullscreen, which I guess is desired?

Another option could be to wrap `PhotoPickerScreen` inside a new StackNavigator and set that navigator to mode='modal'.

You might have to trigger the navigation to that modal from onPress on the tabItem somehow (eg. `navigation.navigate('TakePhoto')`.)

Note, I'm trying to wrap my head around how best to structure navigation myself, so …

Third option, implementing a StackNavigator as parent, then adding the `MyApp` TabNavigator as the first route inside of it, could be the most flexible solution. Then the TakePhoto screen would be on the same level as the TabNavigator, allowing you to route to it from wherever.

Interested to hear what you come up with!

Comment: Yeah I'm still having problems with it myself - did you find a way to set an onPress event on the tab item itself?  I didn't see any way to intercept that tab button press.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two solution

First one is about hide it

For seconde one please read that: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens

```
<Tab.Screen
name={Routes.CREATE_ANNOUNCEMENT_SCREEN}
// name={Routes.TEST_SCREEN}
options={{
.
.
.
  tabBarVisible: false,    <----- solution 1
  tabBarButton: (props) => (   <----- or solution 2
    <TouchableOpacity
      {...props}
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate(Routes.DETAILS_SCREEN);
      }}
    />
  ),
}}
component={CreateAnnouncementScreen}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Docs are patchy in some areas, but here it is:

```
    export default class HomeScene extends Component {

        static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'foo',
        header:{
                    visible: true
                }
        }
        ....
      }
```

Comment: Looks like I pasted totally the wrong code for this answer. My bad. Must have meant to answer a diff question elsewhere