# React Navigation TabNavigator show Modal?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I made an App using `react-navigation` library.

App.js Codes are as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import ProfilePage from './ProfilePage';
import NewsFeedPage from './NewsFeedPage';
import SearchPage from './SearchPage';
import NewPostPage from './NewPostPage';
import FavouritePage from './FavouritePage';

// Tab Bar
const TabBarContainer = TabNavigator({
    NewsFeed: {
        screen: NewsFeedPage,
    },
    Search: {
        screen: SearchPage,
    },
    NewPost: {
        screen: NewPostPage,
    },
    Favourite: {
        screen: FavouritePage,
    },
    Profile: {
        screen: ProfilePage,
    },
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#E87E90',
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom', 
        showLabel: false,
        showIcon: true,
    }
});

export default TabBarContainer;
```

I would like to show the `NewPost` tab in modal way. Is it possible to show modal screen when I switch to a specific tab with `TabNavigator` of `react-navigation` library?

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a solution? I have the same requirement

Comment: I can't find a solution, still.

Comment: Try this way to open modal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398911/how-do-i-make-a-tabnavigator-button-push-a-modal-screen-with-react-navigation/42907868#42907868