# React Native Open Tab Bar in Modal (using expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to have one of the tab bar items open as modal when clicked, I'm currently using expo. I've read this: [How do i make a TabNavigator button push a modal screen with React Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398911/how-do-i-make-a-tabnavigator-button-push-a-modal-screen-with-react-navigation). However, I'm still learning React Native and I'm honestly not sure how to use this using expo navigation. Currently, I have created a stack navigator using "createStackNavigator" for each of the screens. And lastly, I have exported a bottom tab navigator including all of the stacks:

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Tab1Stack,
  Tab2Stack,
  Tab3Stack,
  Tab4Stack
});

I need Tab4 to open as a modal. Can someone people help me with this? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

> Note this was built for "react-navigation": "3.3.0" so your mileage my vary for more recent versions of Expo and `react-navigation`.

To make a modal appear when you tap on the last tab in a `TabNavigator` requires you to nest your `TabNavigator` inside a `StackNavigator`.

So we could set up something like this:

#`App.js`

A simple `App.js`.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppContainer from './MainNavigation';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

#`MainNavigation.js`

This file contains two navigators. A `TabNavigator` and a `StackNavigator`. The `TabNavigator` is nested inside the `StackNavigator`.

To be able to show the `ModalScreen` we have to override the `tabBarOnPress` function inside the `defaultNavigationOptions` which is inside the `config` for the TabNavigator.

We need to check the `navigation.state.key` to see where we are navigating too. If we are going to `Tab3` we can intercept the call and navigate to the `ModalScreen` instead. Otherwise we use the `defaultHandler` and go to the tab that was tapped.

```
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen3';
import ModalScreen from './ModalScreen';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Tab1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Tab2: {
    screen: Screen2
  },
  Tab3: {
    screen: Screen3
  }
};

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Tab1',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: (data) => {
      // this is where the magic happens
      const { navigation, defaultHandler } = data;
      // we check to see if the navigation key is going to be on Tab3
      if (navigation.state.key === 'Tab3') {
        // if it is we show the ModalScreen by navigating to it
        navigation.navigate('ModalScreen');
      } else {
        // otherwise we call the defaultHandler and navigate to the tab we pressed
        defaultHandler(navigation.state.key);
      }
    }
  }
};

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(screens, config);

const stackScreens = {
  Tabs: {
    screen: TabNavigator
  },
  ModalScreen: {
    screen: ModalScreen
  }
};

//we need to set the mode to be modal
const stackConfig = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
  mode: 'modal'
};

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(stackScreens, stackConfig);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

#`Screen.js`

A simple screen for each tab

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Tab Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

#`ModalScreen`

This screen is the modal that will appear when the tab for the third screen is tapped.
As it is part of the `StackNavigator`, defined above, it has access to the navigation prop. We set up a simple button that when pressed calls `this.props.navigation.goBack()` This will dismiss the modal.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Modal Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title={'close modal'}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a snack with it working, https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/show-modal-on-tab-press, hopefully it will show you how to set it up.

Comment: This is the best answer for my case. I needed to navigate between several modal pages. So I used this example but instead of ModalScreen I used a StackNavigator containing all my "modal" pages